# Что же, собственное, такое демотиватор?

Tags: сленг

Посмотрела тут демотиваторы на тему Капитана Очевидности и подумала: а что, собственно, такое демотиватор и почему он так называется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вот это действительно странное слово. Насколько понимаю, у слова нет точной этимологии, если не считать прямого заимствования из английского.
В английском существовало такое понятие как "мотивационный постер" - некий аналог того, что в СССР называли агитплакатом, с поправкой на историческую реальность. 
Поэтому неудивительно, что произведения, пародирующие такие постеры, стали называть "демотивационными", как и сам жанр такой пародии. Или просто демотиваторами. 
Но в английском гораздо лучше ощущается, во-первых, субъектное значение (тот, кто "демотивирует"), и, во-вторых, противопоставление "мотивации". 
В русском прямое заимствование такой прозрачностью не обладает. Уже потому, что понятие "мотивационного постера" было не слишком известно.

Comment: Ну почему, значение довольно прозрачное, даже если слышишь слово в первый раз.

Comment: Откуда б тогда вопрос?
Не, я думаю, что просто кое-кто уже попривык. В первый раз - непонятно.

Comment: Я только на днях увидела это слово (вернее, первый раз - глагол "демотивировать"). Но есть же де-пилятор и де-одорант.  
То есть я, конечно, не вообразила именно картинку, постер. Восприняла "демотиватор" как любой объект, который разрушает мотивацию. Или даже не объект, а личность.

Comment: Я, например, не очень понимаю, как может разрушить мотивацию и мотивацию к чему смешная картинки со смешной (или не очень) подписью?

Comment: А как она увеличит мотивацию - можете представить? 

Высмеивание - мощное орудие. Может, некто надел сандалии с носками, а ему: "Фу, какой моветон", да еще нарисуют. При неустойчивой психике можно и стресс получить.  
Это,конечно, шуточный пример, но принцип тот же. Думаю, все зависит от человека: не каждый поддается внешнему влиянию. Ну, а если поддается - оно может быть и "за" и "против". Тем более рисованный образ действует непосредственнее.

Comment: Посмотрела примеры демотиваторов в интернете, авторы трактуют смысл названия весьма вольно.  Мне понравилась [такая картинка](http://cs14112.vk.me/c540106/v540106452/5907/xoe3RG2fk-k.jpg)

Comment: >Мне понравилась такая картинка  
  
Единственный общепризнанный формальный "признак" демотиватора - картинка на черном фоне с белой надписью типа "заголовок - подзаголовок".    
Ну и юморок, конечно,  должен быть определенного свойства. Но это уже не формализуется.  
Так что эта картинка вполне в теме.  

>но принцип тот же  
  
А вот это как раз - как  сказать. Я бы скорее поверил в демотиватор, высмеивающий того, кто брюзжит по поводу сандалий с носками. Хотя лично для меня это единственное табу в одежде. А так могу хоть при галстухе в драных джинсах ходить. И не только на коленках.